# How can you invite a user in a mobile app that uses Amazon Cognito authentication?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mobile, amazon-cognito

Let's say I have a mobile app that uses Amazon Cognito for authentication (with Facebook and Google providers). In the app I would like to allow my users to create a content and send it to an existing user or another person in the world by providing the person email address.

How can you automatically assign the invited user's account to the created content (only (s)he can access it)? If I understand well you cannot get the new user's email address with Cognito, you only get the Cognito userId.

I can create a code that can be used by the invited user to add the content to its newly registered user account, but I am looking for a more user friendly solution.

Answer (score 0):

You would get a user's email address from the providers. You'll need to ask for permission *and* a provider must have the email address available (not all authentication providers request email addresses from their users)